# Conditional statement for detecting iPhone

Tags: iphone, conditional-statements, statements

I am trying to display something specifically to iPhone users on a web page using conditional statements (like you would with IE).

```
<!--#if expr="(${HTTP_USER_AGENT} = /iPhone/)"-->
Hello
<!--#endif -->
```

This doesn't seem to be hiding itself from non-iPhone users.  Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Recommended reading: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html Also note that iPhone, iPod, and iPad are *all* possibilities for Mobile Safari users. Is there a reason you don't want to do this using conditional CSS?

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't think if that, but it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i ended up solving this via Cody Gray's advice.

CSS:

```
<!--#if expr="(${HTTP_USER_AGENT} = /iPhone/)"-->
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.iPhone {visibility:visible;}
-->
</style>
<!--#else -->
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.iPhone {visibility:hidden}
-->
</style>
<!--#endif -->
```

HTML

```
<div class="iPhone">
Hi
</div>
```

*Edit

I ended up doing this in .net and a placeholder:

Front end:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="myPlaceHolder" runat="server"> 
hi
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code behind:

```
 String userAgent;
        userAgent = Request.UserAgent;
        if (userAgent.IndexOf("iphone") > -1)
        {
            myPlaceHolder.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            myPlaceHolder.Visible = false;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use javascript or server-side processing.

.js:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') > -1)
    document.getElementById('iphoneMessage').style.visibility = 'visible';
```